# How does redis handle parallel update operation for one hash key?

Tags: redis

I have a key (hash type) in redis

Key is

```
service_status:cluster_1
```

Value is like below

```
{
    service_1: normal,
    service_2: normal,
    service_3: normal,
    service_4: normal,
    service_5: down
    ...
}
```

The system is a monitor system. This data is used to store the services status of one cluster.

There are thousands of services in the cluster, so thousands of update request may hit redis to update the same key at the same time.

My concern is how redis handle this? Will there be some lock since these update pointing to the same data?

Comment: You can various benchmarks as well as tools here: https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks. I guess you can simulate your use case with the tools described here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis is single-threaded so there are no "parallel" updates, and therefore no need for locking. Operations in general and updates to a specific hash key, in particular, are executed one at a time.

Comment: I have another concern. Could you please help me on this? My concern is if two different hash-key are going to update in parallel, then those updates are possible in parellel or not?